# What's the best way to cover my egress window (not soft plastic) where the window is above the window well?

Tags: basement, windows, egress

What's the best way to cover an egress window where the cement for the window sticks 11" above the metal window well cover (the window itself is above 10" above the metal window well)? I'm looking for something that will be supportive of people standing or crawling onto the cover itself.

I've seen covers like this:

[image: window well cover]

...but I'm not really sure the best way to do that for windows like mine:
[image: my window measurement 1]

[image: my window measurement 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend against the flimsy dome covers bib recommends in his answer/comment based on safety concerns with children. However, he is on the right track with a domed window well cover, you just need to search for one designed specifically for an egress window that supports weight, covers the full well, and allows egress. Here is an example http://www.egresswindows.com/product/Dome-Cover-5600-Egress-Well/window-well-covers-grates (note this not an endorsement of the linked product).

Comment: We ended up going with one like this http://www.monmatgrp.com/files/client_files/814/418/SDC10281.jpg. (note this not an endorsement of the linked product)

Answer (score 0):

There are [domed window well covers](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Shape-Products-42-in-x-18-in-x-15-in-Thick-Strong-Circular-Bubble-4217CBT/202936307) for these applications.

[image: window well cover]

A search of *window well covers* should give you leads for the rights size and material.

Note that egress windows must be easily exited. If this is an egress window, check your local code to see if a cover is allowed and how removable it must be.

```
 Images and links are illustrative only, not an endorsement of goods or sources.
```

Comment: I didn't think the domed ones were supportive of people standing on them or falling into them...

Comment: Part of the problem is that any cover has to be easy to open in an emergency. A heavy duty (and heavy weight) unit over the well will likely defeat the purpose.